# NodeJS FileUpload - Cannot read property Undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Im using NodeJS, ExpressJS, mongoose, EJS.

upload form:

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='text' name='photo[name]'/>
    <input type='file' name='photo[image]'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload'/>
</form>
```

model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/photo_app');
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    path: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Photo', schema);
```

`app.js`:

```
var app = express();
...
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
...
```

route:

```
var Photo = require('../models/Photo');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var join = path.join;

exports.submit = function (dir) {
    return function(req, res, next){
        var img = req.files.photo.image;
        var name = req.body.photo.name || img.name;
        var path = join(dir, img.name);
        fs.rename(img.path, path, function(err){
            if (err)
                return next(err);
            Photo.create({
                name: name,
                path: img.name
            }, function (err) {
                if (err)
                    return next(err);
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        });
    };
};
```

The problem when trying to upload:

```
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine. Which line is throwing the error, `var img = ...` or `var name = ...`?

Comment: The error is in the line`var name = req.body.photo.name || img.name;` Error occurred after uploading a file.

Comment: This is what I tried https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5722884. Notice that I changed the upload dir of `bodyParse` to avoid partition problems.

Comment: @rvidal, were u able to upload image file?

Comment: Yes, it worked. BTW the gist had a typo (`filez`), but otherwise is the thing I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and what I did was pass a couple of options into the bodyParser object.

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + '/public/photos' }));
```

After I put added the option everything seemed to work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use connect-multiparty  and  include it  in your route file:

```
var multipart=require('connect-multiparty');
```

Then use as:

```
app.post('/uploads',multipart(),function(req,res){
    // ...
});
```